# PHP: Help modifying tables on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-connection

Following this following example...

```
    public function insert($model,$brand,$price){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO autos (model, brand, price) VALUES ($model,'$brand', $price)",$this->link);} 

$conexion-> insert(05,"Ford",50000000);
```

...I made a modify/update code:

```
public function modify($model,$brand,$price,$newbrand,$newprice){
            mysql_query("UPDATE 'crautos'.'autos' SET 'brand' = '$newbrand',
'price' = '$newprice' WHERE 'autos'.'model' =5 AND 'autos'.'brand' = '$brand' AND 'autos'.'price' ='$price' LIMIT 1) VALUES ($newbrand, $newprice)",$this->link);}

$conexion-> modify("Mitsubishi", 40000000);
```

But it didn't work, this is the error output:

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for MyDataBase::modify(), called in on
>   line 15 Warning: Missing argument 4 for MyDataBase::modify(), called
>   in on line 28 and defined in on line 15 Warning: Missing argument 5
>   for MyDataBase::modify(), called in on line 28 and defined in on line
>   15 AND undefined variable newprice, newbrand, price. THE Insert code
>   is fine, and the modify code is causing the issue.

Here's the full code:

```
    <?php

class MyDataBase{
    private $link;

    public function __construct($server,$user,$password,$base){
        //Conectar
        $this->link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
        mysql_select_db($base,$this->link);
        }

        public function insert($model,$brand,$price){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO autos (model, brand, price) VALUES ($model,'$brand', $price)",$this->link);}

        public function modify($model,$brand,$price,$newbrand,$newprice){
            mysql_query("UPDATE 'crautos'.'autos' SET 'brand' = '$newbrand',
'price' = '$newprice' WHERE 'autos'.'model' =5 AND 'autos'.'brand' = '$brand' AND 'autos'.'price' ='$price' LIMIT 1) VALUES ($newbrand, $newprice)",$this->link);}

        public function __destruct(){
        //desconectar
        }

}


$conexion = new MyDataBase ('localhost', 'root', '','crcars');
$conexion-> insert(05,"Ford",50000000);
$conexion-> modify("Mitsubishi", 40000000);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an invalid syntax in the update query. You do no need the VALUES part. Here is how it should be:

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE 'crautos'.'autos' SET 'brand' = '$newbrand', 'price' = '$newprice' WHERE 'autos'.'model' =5 AND 'autos'.'brand' = '$brand' AND 'autos'.'price' ='$price' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Thanks, all the errors have gone but now I'm getting unexpected T_STRING on line 27, which is: $conexion-> insert(05,"Ford",50000000);

Comment: it is a syntax error... maybe some parenthesis is missing. Examine your code carefully, probably you have overridden the } closing bracket when you we coping my code

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE syntax is invalid, like @Martin pointed out, also you're calling modify() with two parameters, but the function is expecting 5.  Add the extra values to `$conexion-> modify("Mitsubishi", 40000000);`

Something like:

```
$conexion-> modify("Mitsubishi", 40000000, $price, $newbrand, $newprice);
```

Comment: Thanks, all the errors have gone but now I'm getting unexpected T_STRING on line 27, which is: $conexion-> insert(05,"Ford",50000000); This was not happening before, since I haven't done anything to this older line of code...

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but try enclosing the 05 in quotes.  Most IDE's should highlight syntax errors like that, btw.

Comment: I managed to find the mistake, but I'm still getting  Undefined variable for $price,$newbrand,$newprice. All related to line 28, which is: $conexion-> modify('Mitsubishi',40000000,$price,$newbrand,$newprice);

Comment: You have to replace $price, $newbrand, $newprice with the actual values you're trying to modify.  You could upvote/accept, btw, I get paid in stackoverflow karma.